# Fastest and efficient way to get record using Entity Framework and C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am beginner and I am using a function which takes approximately 20 seconds to load a record - please is there any other, more efficient and faster way to execute this? How i can include `guest id` with `guest name` so that its works faster rather then use `for each loop` to assign `guest name` with `guest id`

**Data.Tables.Booking**

```
    [Table("Bookings")]
public class Booking : ITrackable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int GuestId { get; set; }

    public int RoomId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CheckInDateTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime CheckOutDateTime { get; set; }

    public decimal DailyPricePerBed { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Memo { get; set; }
    public string PriceType { get; set; }

    public bool Paid { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime ChangedAt { get; set; }
    public string? InvoiceType { get; set; }
   
}
```

**Booking model**

```
  public class Booking : BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.ERROR_REQUIRED)]
    [Display(Name = "Gast")]
    public int GuestId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.ERROR_REQUIRED)]
    [Display(Name = "Zimmer")]
    public int RoomId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.ERROR_REQUIRED)]

    [Display(Name = "Check-In")]
    public DateTime CheckInDateTime { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.ERROR_REQUIRED)]
    [Display(Name = "Check-Out")]
    public DateTime CheckOutDateTime { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.ERROR_REQUIRED)]
    [Display(Name = "Tagespreis pro Bett")]


    public decimal DailyPricePerBed { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.ERROR_REQUIRED)]
    [Display(Name = "Price Type required")]
    public string PriceType { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = Constants.ERROR_MAX_LENGHT)]
    [Display(Name = "Sonstiges")]
    public string Memo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Bezahlt")]
    public bool Paid { get; set; }

    public List<Guest> Guests { get; set; }

    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }

    public string GuestName { get; set; }

    public string TitleBooking { get; set; }

    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }

    public RoomType RoomType { get; set; }
    public string EncryptedRoomId { get; set; }
    public string EncryptedPartnerId { get; set; }
    public string? InvoiceType { get; set; }



}
```

}

```
public List<Booking> Load(int roomId)
{
    var result = _context.Bookings
                         .Where(item => item.RoomId == roomId)
                         .Select(item => _mapper.Map<Booking>(item))
                         .ToList();
     //its takes time here to load each guest name, if i remove 
   //this part 
 //its works fast but its showing guest ids on calendar, i want 
 //to show guest name
    foreach (var booking in result)
    {
        if (_context.Guests.Any(o => o.Id == booking.GuestId)) // update
        {
            booking.GuestName = _guestRepository.GetName(booking.GuestId);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Show model classes with navigation properties.

Comment: **What** part is slow? Loading the data from the database? Then you need to performance-optimize your database structure. Converting the loaded row using `_mapper` ? Tweak the mappings to improve performance.....

Comment: `if (_context.Guests.Any` you are performing another sql query inside your loop. Don't do that.

Comment: @marc_s slow is this part `foreach (var booking in result)
    {
        if (_context.Guests.Any(o => o.Id == booking.GuestId)) // update
        {
            booking.GuestName = _guestRepository.GetName(booking.GuestId);
        }
    }`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv please check my above modified detail question, hope you guys understand

Answer (score 1):

You code will be slow for two main reasons. Firstly you are selecting a set of Bookings then using Automapper to "Map" these across to copies of Booking entity classes. If Bookings contain navigation property references to other entities and you have Lazy Loading enabled, this is quite likely resulting in a LOT of lazy load hits as Mapper.Map "touches" each navigation property as it's iterating through the Bookings to copy the object graph across. You are then going and iterating over each booking to call to the GuestRepository to get the guest name, and that could also be of varying efficiency. For instance does the repository do something like:

```
return _context.Guests.Where(g => g.GuestId == guestId).Select(g => g.GuestName).Single();
```

or does it do something like:

```
var guest = _context.Guests.Single(g => g.GuestId == guestId);
return guest.GuestName;
```

The first runs an SQL Statement to retrieve one column for one row. The second reads *all* columns from Guest and builds a Guest entity for one row, just to return one value.

The first thing would be to ensure that you have navigation properties defined for all relationships, such as between Bookings and Guests.

From your example I'm guessing this code is part of a BookingRepository which has a dependency on a GuestRepository to get guest information. If there is one piece of advice I can give, it is to ***avoid*** the Generic Repository pattern in EF, or thinking of Repositories as serving individual entities. Instead, design Repositories to serve business needs, like a Controller in MVC. If I have a BookingController set up to serve everything to do with making/reviewing bookings, then I can have a BookingRepository to handle all Domain interactions  for that Controller. Not just Booking entities, but everything needed for making/reviewing bookings.

The next thing is handling projection. Returning entities outside of the scope of a DbContext that reads them is generally not a great idea. Entities represent data domain. Views have their own concerns with regards to what data they need, and how they want to present it. They should have a purpose-built representation of the domain they are concerned with, a View Model.

So for instance if we have a Booking entity, it should be associated with a Room and a Guest. Each of these would be entities for their respective tables and linked by FKs within the Booking table. What the view is concerned with isn't everything in the Booking, Room, and Guest, just bits of details which can be flattened down from the respective tables and columns. For instance:

```
public class BookingViewModel
{
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public int GuestId { get; set; }
    public string RoomNumber { get; set;}
    public string GuestName { get; set; }
}
```

Now when we fetch bookings for a given room, without diving into Repositories yet, just working with a DbContext and it's entities:

```
var bookings = _context.Bookings
    .Where(b => b.RoomId == roomId)
    .Select(b => new BookingViewModel
    {
        BookingId = b.BookingId,
        RoomId = b.Room.RoomId,
        GuestId = b.Guest.GuestId,
        RoomNumber = b.Room.RoomNumber,
        GuestName = b.Guest.LastName + ", " + b.Guest.FirstName
    }).ToList();
```

With Automapper, we can configure mapping rules for translating a Booking and it's related structure into this BookingViewModel and the above can be simplified to something looking like:

```
var bookings = _context.Bookings
    .Where(b => b.RoomId == roomId)
    .ProjectTo<BookingViewModel>(mapperConfig)
    .ToList();
```

Where "mapperConfig" is an instance of a MapperConfiguration set up with the rules to translate Booking -> BookingViewModel. This could be one global Config, or a config built as requested by a factory method.

The benefits with either `Select` or `ProjectTo` is that the projection goes directly to the SQL Query so the only data returned is what is needed to populate the view model. There are no risks of lazy loading surprises, or even worrying about tracked entities bogging down the DbContext.

When starting out I would get the hang of using the DbContext and projection *without* introducing a Repository pattern. The EF DbContext acts as both a Unit of Work and Repository in the sense, and trying to abstract that fact from your application can mean introducing significant performance and flexibility penalties.

For introducing repositories I would recommend either a Repository pattern and Unit of Work pattern that leverage `IQueryable` so that callers can project details as they need, or having repositories that abstract the domain (entities) into the needs of the consumer. (view models)  `IQueryable` provides a lot of flexibility making Repositories easy to mock for testing, but are coupled to Entity Framework as consumers need to know that fact and manage the DbContext's Scope to use them effectively. Designing repositories that return ViewModels creates a cleaner boundary to isolate consumers from EF, but requires the Repository to have a larger footprint to accommodate all methods, variants, and concerns for the consumer(s). For instance supporting sorting, pagination, etc. Structuring Repositories to serve individual controllers can certainly help compared to repositories-per-entity that serve many controllers with different concerns.

**Edit:** If updating the result to a view model represents too big of a change, do keep these details in mind for future work because the approach your code base is using is highly inefficient. You Can mitigate the problem to a degree with some smaller changes including loading the entities detached and using `Include` to Eager-load the required relationships.

The first change would be moving the GuestName into a domain concern that the entity can resolve. Inside the Booking entity change:

```
public string GuestName { get; set; }
```

to:

```
private string _guestName = null;
public string GuestName
{
    get 
    { 
        return _guestName ?? (_guestName = Guests.SingleOrDefault(g => g.GuestId == GuestId)?.Name;
    }
    set { _guestName = value; }
}
```

If you are using .Net Core 6 or 7 this can be simplified to:

```
private string? _guestName = null;
public string? GuestName
{
    get => _guestName ??= Guests.SingleOrDefault(item => item.GuestId == GuestId)?.Name;
    set => _guestName = value;
}
```

Rather than going to the repository for every guest record to get the name, let the entity go to its Guests collection. (if available) This is written as to not break existing code, so any code that "Sets" the guest name will still take precedence.

Alternatively you could use the setter like you are and just go to booking.Guests to get the applicable guest's name rather than going to the repository:

```
foreach (var booking in result)
{
    booking.GuestName = booking.Guests.FirstOrDefault(item => item.GuestId == booking.GuestId)?.Name;
}
```

If the guest name needs to be formatted from a Guest First and Last Name:

```
foreach (var booking in result)
{
    var mainGuest = booking.Guests.FirstOrDefault(item => item.GuestId == booking.GuestId);
    if (mainGuest == null) continue;

    booking.GuestName = $"{mainGuest.LastName}, {mainGuest.FirstName}";
}
```

For methods like this to work, whether using the property or getting the guest from the Guests collection and using the Setter, the entity must have the Guests collection eager loaded, which is the next step:

Eager load any required details your view is going to need about the guest, and detach them:

```
var result = _context.Bookings
    .Include(item => item.Guests)
    .Where(item => item.RoomId == roomId)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```

This will do something similar to your original code, but it will eager load the Bookings collection, and it will detach the resulting entities so that they won't be lazy-loadable proxies or have changes tracked by the DbContext. The issue with using `Mapper.Map` without `AsNoTracking` is that if your DbContext is set up to use lazy loading, the `Mapper.Map` call will go through each property, which when it hits a navigation property, trigger a lazy load. This will ensure that all data is mapped, but it is ***extremely*** slow and inefficient. The above example eager loads the Bookings collection. If there are other navigation properties your view will *touch*, these will very likely currently be #null now, so you will need to ensure they are eager loaded using `Include` as well.

Eager loading with `Include` does come with some performance issues when dealing with one-to-many relationships, especially eager loading several one-to-many relationships in that it produces Cartesian Products where the total volume of data grows by factors with the more relationships you load. This will typically be faster than lazy loading, but still represents a significant resource and performance cost. This is why projecting to a view model is recommended. You will still generate a Cartesian Product, but across far fewer fields as the projection only selects the fields you actually need rather than everything in the associated table. If you are using Eager Loading, eager load only what you know you will need, *not* everything, or you will soon be facing similar performance and memory bloat problems.

Comment: I am sorry i cannot create new class of `bookingviewmodel` because i need to change complete code also my class is inherit with base class o i cannot create new class

Comment: please check my updated question , i provide details , please help

Comment: I have updated the answer to include a possible work-around with the existing Entity usage which should help, but definitely consider changing your approach to use view models rather than passing entities around as it will avoid many of the performance pitfalls you are getting tripped up by.

Comment: hi, i apply your code but its showing error [link](https://paste.pics/LM82O)

Comment: You need to add `.Include(item => item.Guests)` to your query for the Bookings. (My original code example had a typo referencing item.Bookings)   The work-around relies on the relationships referenced need to be eager loaded. When declaring navigation properties to Collections you should pre-initialize the collection to a new List<Guest>(). I.e. `public virtual ICollection<Guest> Guests { get; set; } = new List<Guest>();`  This helps avoid nullRefExeptions when setting up new Bookings or situations where they aren't eager loaded or no guests are present without extra null checks everywhere..

Answer (score 0):

As comments have pointed out, you have not specified which of the parts of that function is consuming the time, nor is it clear what your model looks like.

However, I shall make two assumptions:

1. the problem is that you are looping through result and then hitting the database for each booking, perhaps twice.
2. the Guest name property is in the Guests entity / table.

If so, something like the following should speed it up by minimising the database calls to two for the whole function.

```
// Database Call 1
var result = _context.Bookings
                     .Where(item => item.RoomId == roomId)
                     .Select(item => _mapper.Map<Booking>(item))
                     .ToList();

// Get the Guest Ids used in the booking retrieved above
List<int> guestIds = result.Select(b => b.GuestId).Distinct().ToList();

// Get all Guests that are used - Database Call 2
List<Guest> guests = _context.Guests.Where(g => guestIds.Contains(g.Id)).ToList();

// Now put the name on the bookings
foreach (var booking in result)
{
    Guest? guest = guests.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Id == booking.GuestId);

    if (guest is not null)
    {
        booking.GuestName = guest.Name;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you have a navigation property to guest from booking, then you can retrieve the guest along with the booking in a single database call like so:

```
var result = _context.Bookings
                 .Include(b => b.Guest)
                 .Where(b => b.RoomId == roomId)
                 ... etc.
```

Comment: For me it's obvious which part is slow, so I do not answer before additional details. And `Include` with `Select` has no sense.

Comment: I can understand you choosing not to answer before additional details, but I felt that the answer could help a self-described beginner on their way.  I agree with your comment about `Include` and `Select`, hence my "etc ..." as if the OP moves to using a navigation property the redundancy of Select would become apparent.

Comment: Since you only iterate the result of your call to `.ToList()`, it's better to call `.ToArray()` instead. The iteration is significantly faster. https://www.meziantou.net/copying-a-collection-tolist-vs-toarray.htm

Comment: @NeilW your code showing error please check screenshot [link](https://paste.pics/LLGDW)

Comment: @NeilW this is slow due to this part of code  `foreach (var booking in result)
            {
                
                if (_context.Guests.Any(o => o.Id == booking.GuestId)) 
                {
                    booking.GuestName = _guestRepository.GetName(booking.GuestId);
                }
            }`

Comment: @NeilW if i just remove above part of code then its works fast,

Comment: @NeilW please check my updated details question

Comment: @don - Have updated my answer with a cast ToList() where you had the error.  Yes, I would expect your code to run fast if you remove that part, as it is that part that is hitting the database multiple times for each item in the result.

Comment: its still showing same error which i send you earlier, i dont know which thing you update